# Constructor seemed to have assigned pointer correctly, but pointer changes outside constructor

Tags: pointers, constructor, memory-leaks, malloc, intel-mkl

I currently have a class that have a contructor based on importing some values from npz to a double pointer A.

```cpp
StateSystem::StateSystem(std::string filename)
{
    cnpy::NpyArray A_npy = cnpy::npz_load(filename, "A");
    StateSystem::A = (double *)mkl_malloc(A_npy.shape[0] * A_npy.shape[1] * sizeof(double), 64);
    this->StateSystem::A = A_npy.data<double>();

    std::cout << "A (in constructor):" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < StateSystem::n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < StateSystem::n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << " " << StateSystem::A[j + StateSystem::n * i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Since this is some assignment of mkl_malloc on pointers, I try to be careful and try do some checks that the value imported is correct.

I tried with npz where A contains Id, and from the constructor, the last lines print correctly:

```bash
A (in constructor):
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1
```

However, when I created a class method where it prints the variable, my variables seem to change.

```cpp
void StateSystem::info()
{
std::cout \<\< UNDERLINE \<\< "State system: n=" \<\< StateSystem::n \<\< " m=" \<\< StateSystem::m \<\< " p=" \<\< StateSystem::p \<\< CLOSEUNDERLINE \<\< std::endl;
std::cout \<\< "A:" \<\< std::endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i \< StateSystem::n; i++)
{
for (size_t j = 0; j \< StateSystem::n; j++)
{
std::cout \<\< " " \<\< StateSystem::A\[j + StateSystem::n \* i\] \<\< " ";
}
std::cout \<\< std::endl;
}
```

This function leads to:

```bash
State system: n=4 m=1 p=1
A:
1\.13825e-313  -1.74758e+260  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1
```

Any idea why???

Comment: I think `this->StateSystem::A = A_npy.data<double>();` only copies the pointer to the data, but not the contents, and once you leave the constructor, you actually read from a pointer that was already freed.